# how to avoid drag and drop in picklist primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

I have a problem while using picklist. i dont know how to avoid drag and drop in picklist.
i am using primefaces 3.2 some one please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was answered [here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=23872).

In short, PrimeFaces doesn't give you the option to disable drag and drop (as of version 3.3) on `p:pickList`.

Since the problem was manly the fact that one could drag items anywhere on the screen, a [new issue was created](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4469) targeting version 3.4. This enhancement is going to prevent dragging items out of the `p:pickList` container.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the init method and disable jQuery sortable:

```
/* Deactivate drag and drop */
if (PrimeFaces.widget.PickList) {
    PrimeFaces.widget.PickList = PrimeFaces.widget.PickList.extend({
        init : function(cfg) {
            this._super(cfg);
            $(this.jqId + " ul").sortable("disable");
        }
    });
}
```